# Overflow css is causing dropdown window behind row below rather than display above it

Tags: html, css

I have a table that contains rows of items. Ever other row is an expandable row that will hold the inventory table for the above item for that user.

This row can be expanded to a `max-height` of `300px` and collapsed again. This row contains a table which holds the inventory rows for the user. These rows contain input fields and dropdown fields so users can modify specific inventory records for condition, language, etc.

I have set the max height for this row to 300px and if I was to not have an overflow CSS value the dropdown window works as expected by then if a user adds too many rows, then they won't be able to scroll through them.

[image]

The issue I am facing is when the overflow set to scroll, the dropdown window is hidden within the confines of the div and just seems to expand the inner part of the div as seen in a screenshot below. How do I get it so that the dropdown window pops out of the div, and the scroll is that of the height of the table within and not the table plus the dropwown.

[image]

[image]

I am using [choices.js](https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices) for my dropdown menu.

I have added the code to codepen to display the problem I am seeing:

https://codepen.io/goosedeersolutions/pen/WNyYdzm

Comment: I've turned your code into a snippet and added choices.js, and as you can see - we can't reproduce your layout. I'll follow the question and check back when that's fixed :)

Comment: I am not sure how to use the code snippet, but I have added the code to Codepen which displays the issue.

Comment: It's worth using the SO snippet system - offsite sites may disappear in future, rendering your question not useful for future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with creating a snippet.

Comment: Looks like this is a common failing of Choices.js (https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices/issues/504) The maintainers basically say that you should change your design. ‍♂️